# Fixed top row in table and unintended resize

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have implemented a table on my website with a fixed top row that will move together with the header navigation when viewers scroll the page. The table is included in a MaterializeCSS tab (https://materializecss.com/tabs.html).

To include the div within a specific tab, the table is wrapped in a div with the id of "tab1". However, when I include this id, the top row of the table for some reason resizes to less than the full width of the table. This error doesn't occur as long as I don't include the id. I tried to replicate the error in a JSFiddle but this is a bit complex due to all the coding I have on the site. I am certain that the error is due to the Javascript code for setting the fixed table row and was hoping that someone would be able to spot what is causing this.

```
<script>
  (function($) {
    $.fn.fixMe = function() {
      return this.each(function() {
        var $this = $(this),
          $t_fixed, $table_wrap, $table_header_wrap, $container,
          $header_height = $('nav').height();

        function init() {
          $container = $this.parent();
          $table_header_wrap = $('<div>').addClass('table_header_wrap').insertAfter($this);
          $table_wrap = $('<div>').addClass('table_wrap').insertAfter($table_header_wrap).append($this);
          $t_fixed = $this.clone().find("tbody").remove().end().hide().appendTo($table_header_wrap);
          $table_header_wrap.css({
            top: $header_height + "px"
          }).on('scroll', header_wrap_scroll);
          resizeFixed();
        }

        function resizeFixed() {
          $table_header_wrap.width($container.width() + 10);
          //$table_wrap.width($container.width());
          $t_fixed.width($this.width() + 2);
          $t_fixed.find("th").each(function(index) {
            $(this).css("width", $this.find("th").eq(index).outerWidth() + "px");
          });
        }

        function scrollFixed() {
          var offset = $(this).scrollTop(),
            tableOffsetTop = $this.offset().top,
            tableOffsetBottom = tableOffsetTop + $this.height() - $this.find("thead").height();
          if (offset + $header_height < tableOffsetTop || offset + $header_height > tableOffsetBottom)
            $t_fixed.hide();
          else if (offset + $header_height >= tableOffsetTop && offset + $header_height <= tableOffsetBottom && $t_fixed.is(":hidden"))
            $t_fixed.show();
        }

        function header_wrap_scroll() {
          $table_wrap.scrollLeft($table_header_wrap.scrollLeft());
        }
        $(window).resize(resizeFixed);
        $(window).scroll(scrollFixed);
        init();
      });
    };
  })(jQuery);

  $(document).ready(function() {
    $("table").fixMe();
  });
  </script>
```

The HTML is quite simple but an example is included below to show the structure of the table with id set to tab1 as mentioned above:

```
<div id="tab1" class="table1">
  <table class="">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>#</th>
            <th>First Name</th>
            <th>Last Name</th>
            <th>Username</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>Mark</td>
            <td>Otto</td>
            <td>@mdo</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>Jacob</td>
            <td>Thornton</td>
            <td>@fat</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well... It would have been preferable to see a working fiddle, but the only function that seems to deal specifically with widths in absolutes, that would have the described effect is in your resizeFixed function, where you are setting the width of each TH in Pixels:

```
$t_fixed.find("th").each(function(index) {
   $(this).css("width", $this.find("th").eq(index).outerWidth() + "px");
});
```

Perhaps if you changed to min-width it might make less of an impact.

Comment: Hi Jan. Thanks for helping out with this. I notice you are Danish as well. I could need some professional help going forward. Feel free to reach out at roa@nordicstocks.com if you are curious about this!